# Hibernate throwing Staleobjectstate exception accessed in a single thread caused by last modified on timestamp

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, exception, last-modified

I have a some objects, with its hibernate xml (legacy system):

```
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
   <column name="id" />
   <generator class="increment" />
 </id>

  <timestamp name="lastModifiedOn" column="last_modified_on" />
  ...
```

in servlets the objects are added and update etc. Using postgresql the servlets work and no exception is thrown. 
Using MSSQL, when only a single user is accessing the servlet, staleobjectstate exception in thrown that the row was updated or deleted by another transaction.

Hibernate SQL showed that it issues update statements on its own in the servlet. When explicitly hibernate's update method is called, it throws the error.

```
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

and the weird part is that the sql for updating the object is:

```
update
    equipment 
set
    last_modified_on=?,
    created_on=?,
    public_id=?,
    vendor_id=?,
    created_by=?,
    last_modified_by=?,
    equipment_id=? 
where
    ID=?
    and last_modified_on=?
```

that its checking based on ID and last modified on? why not just ID?
Only ID field is PK in the db.
Only one user is accessing the servlet.

For the moment I have changed the last modified on from timestamp to property, throughout the system and the error is gone. also the sql that is generated by hibernate now only checks based on ID.

```
  <timestamp name="lastModifiedOn" column="last_modified_on" />
```

to

```
  <property type="timestamp" name="lastModifiedOn" column="last_modified_on" />
```

However, now the the field last_modified_on in the db (datetime) wont get updated automatically with the latest time, contains null now, and have to do it programmatically which is quite a pain to make this change, even with interception.

Is there any way that I can still use the lastModifiedOn as timestamp, and get rid of that stale object state exception.

Comment: I have a similar problem on Postgresql. The `last_modified_on` timestamp value in the database is different by a few milliseconds from the `java.util.Date lastMondifiedOn` value used by Hibernate in the update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use version.

In DAO you can check rowversion before update.

```
<version name="rowVersion" column="ROW_VERSION" type="java.lang.Long" />
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. shall i add another column version in all the objects and tables to keep a version number and then update all the places where an object is updated to add this check?